# How to refresh Word doc page numbers in vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

I have a VBA macro that cleans a 2010 Word document. Actually, it removes empty rows on many tables.

At the end of the function, I would like to create a table of contents with the titles and page numbers of all tables in the document.

```
Dim tTable As Table
tTable.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

The problem is, cleaning the tables reduced the length of the document from 30 pages to 25 pages. When I call `.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)` the page indexes have not been updated yet.

I tried to call `Sleep` for a while but it doesn't work either.

I'm not a VBA specialist, but is there a function to force update the page numbers of a document?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found the function to call:

```
ActiveDocument.Repaginate
```

It seems to work fine!